# Opencart change product price upon user order

Tags: opencart

I hope my Q will make sense but I am really out of ideas.

I will explain by example: http://www.xtdeco.ro/fototapet/texturat/Bloom-R12241-6

There is a standard product, with some attributes.

What I need to do is make this product configurable, as you may notice the two text inputs. The plan is to calculate the Lățime*Înălțime, multiply by price / sqm, verify against the actual product price (no problem this far) and then add or subtract a value to the product price, or add a option to the product for the current cart that would do the same.

Is there anyone with a idea of how this could be done without hacking to much of the sources?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to **not let** the user to input his concrete dimensions but to let him choose from prepared one.

If this is a wallpaper and You know the role of this wallpaper is always only 1m wide (just for simplicity) then for example sell only this 1m<sup>2</sup> and let the user to enter the *amount of pieces* which will result in that long piece cut from the role (so 8 piecese (m<sup>2</sup>) ordered result in 8m long piece of role that is 1m wide). In this case You may change the word *pieces* or *quantity* for **m<sup>2</sup>**.

If this is a wall print with concrete dimensions (or aspect ratio), let the user choose from some predefined sizes, e.g.

- **XS** (120 x 170 cm) **+ $0**
- **S** (150 x 212.5 cm) **+ $10**
- **M** (200 x 283 cm) **+ $20**
- **L** (250 x 354 cm) **+ $35**
- **XL** (300 x 425 cm) **+ $50**

This may be handled by the product options which is again easier than what are You requesting... Don't You think?

**EDIT** based on comment:

Then there is only one possibility that comes to my mind:

- hide the quantity field (don't remove, make it `hidden`)
- create some JS `onChange` event handling function, that will listen to `onChange`, `onBlur`, `onKeyUp` (whetever) events on both text fields (for dimensions) and this will calculate the resulting area size in m<sup>2</sup> which will be shown to the costumer as well as **price per that m<sup>2</sup>** while price per 1m<sup>2</sup> is also known and displayed to the customer
- this function will also fill the calculated float value into the hidden quantity field so after adding to the cart the cart should contain smth like

> 4.73m<sup>2</sup> WallPrint1 $18.92

(because I was calculating the price $4 for 1m<sup>2</sup>, thus 4m<sup>2</sup> x 4.73 $/m<sup>2</sup> = $18.92)

I'm not sure but maybe You will have to edit some other pieces of code to allow You to add float quantity values into cart annd also to order them...

Comment: The option with the predefined sizes is indeed a solution, but what I don't like about this is that it constrains the costumer to some fixed sizes.

The idea is to give the costumer the power to fully customize the wallpaper according to his needs, so that he could get a size of 234x498 if be needed.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense! Thank you!